# How can a read a variable number of variable from the keyboard? C++

Tags: c++, variables, keyboard, numbers

I want to read one or two values from keyboard, the first one represents the `length_min` and the second one is the `length_max`. In the input stream I can get one value and I can check if there's another value using `cin.get()`, but when I read one number from keyboard, I have to introduce another character to print the correct values.

The template for reading:

`length + 'length_min'` and/or not `'length_max'` (read `length_max` if in that line exists another digits after `length_min`).

```
string length;
cin >> length;

int length_min, length_max;
cin >> length_min;

cin.ignore();  // there's a whitespace between length_min and length_max
char c = cin.get();

if (isdigit(c)) // I verified if there's a digit which represents the length_max
{
    ungetc(c, stdin);
    cin >> length_max;
}
else
{
    cin.ignore(); // if there's no digit go to next line in input stream 
    length_max = 0;
}
```

For these examples:

`length 5 8` -> it prints `5 8`

`length 5 + any character` -> it prints `5 0`

I what to get rid of that additional character, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Your question don't have an [MCVE] so it is not very clear. Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Maybe you want to use [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) (since the standard input is *not* the keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read two variables from the console:

```
int variable_1;
int variable_2;
std::cin >> variable_1 >> variable_2;
```

If the second variable is optional, your best method is to read one line at a time, then parse the line:

```
std::string text;
while (std::getline(std::cin, text))
{
  std::istringstream input(text);
  input >> variable_1;
  if (input >> variable_2)
  {
     // Do stuff with variable_2
  }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! ;)